# Apple's Numbers app: How to use current column number to get some cell on certain row

Tags: macos, apple-numbers, apple-numbers-formula

### Preconditions

I can get only the current column number by formula `=COLUMN()`, that by the lack of argument gives me it, in the cell it's written.

### Objectives

I want to use it for selecting a cell in some row.
It must be something like:

```
=COLUMN()$3
```

Which means - select the cell on 3d row and current column of the cell the function is in.

**P.S**
*But this type of syntax above is invalid*
*Question is present here due to the lack of quality documentation on apple's developer's discussions and other resources*

Comment: something like `=INDIRECT(COLUMN() & "3")`

Comment: @Iłya Bursov
Tried, doesn't work. It shows 0. Don't know does it depend on OS version, i'm on Ventura.

Comment: `COLUMN()` returns a number, e.g. for a cell in column B, `COLUMN()` will return 2. The `ADDRESS()` function can be used to construct a cell address that can be used with `INDIRECT()`., e.g. `INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3,COLUMN()))`.

Comment: See the [Formulas and Functions Help](https://support.apple.com/guide/functions/welcome/13.2/web) for Numbers

Comment: @Jonathan Dodds
Yeah, that works, thanks you a lot, i've seen the help page, but something gone wrong or i missed valuable info there.

Comment: @Jonathan Dodds
You can post a full answer to close the question a got approved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`COLUMN`](https://support.apple.com/guide/functions/column-ffa599e753/13.2/web/1.0) function does accept an argument but when no argument is provided, `COLUMN` uses the cell that contains the formula.

`COLUMN` returns a number. For a cell in column B, `=COLUMN()` will return `2`.  A valid cell address string uses letters for the column.

The [`ADDRESS`](https://support.apple.com/guide/functions/address-ffa59ca516/13.2/web/1.0) function is used to construct a cell address string (e.g. "B3")). `=ADDRESS(3,COLUMN())` will create an address for row 3 for the same column.

The [`INDIRECT`](https://support.apple.com/guide/functions/indirect-ffa596db0e/13.2/web/1.0) function will retrieve the content of a cell for a given cell address, e.g. `INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3,COLUMN()))`.

From within Numbers, the 'Help' -> 'Formula and Functions Help' menu should open the [Formulas and Functions Help](https://support.apple.com/guide/functions/welcome/13.2/web) guide. The functions discussed are all in the "Reference Functions" section which can be navigated to from the "Table of Contents".